# Why am i getting ImportError in this code?

Tags: python, importerror

```
import pyfiglet
from termcolor import colored

total_colors = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "magenta", "cyan", "white"]

msg = input("What would you like to print?  ")
col = input("what color?")

if col not in total_colors:
    col = "green"

ascii_art = pyfiglet.figlet_format(msg)
colored_ascii = colored(ascii_art, color=col)
print(colored_ascii)
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'figlet_format' from 'pyfiglet'

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: It may be a wrapper on the figlet program (a separate program from Python). You might have to install `figlet` as well.

Comment: The code works for me, maybe try to reinstall `pyfiglet`?

Comment: I suspect a name clash. Is there anything called `pyfiglet` in your project?

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues i see in your program.

1.install pyfiglet module
`pip install pyfiglet`

2.`msg = input("What would you like to print? ")`
no need to take in put on this line as next line takes input and logic of your program is based on the next input

3.`ascii_art = pyfiglet.figlet_format(msg) colored_ascii = colored(ascii_art, color=col) print(colored_ascii)`

The above line should be

`ascii_art = pyfiglet.figlet_format(col) colored_ascii = colored(ascii_art, color=col) print(colored_ascii)`

I installed the pyfiglet module and did implement modified program

```
import pyfiglet
from termcolor import colored

total_colors = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "magenta", "cyan", "white"]

msg = print("What would you like to print? ")
col = input("what color?")

if col not in total_colors: col = "green"

ascii_art = pyfiglet.figlet_format(col)
colored_ascii = colored(ascii_art, color=col)
print(colored_ascii)
```

Output:

```
What would you like to print? 
what color?blue
[34m _     _            
| |__ | |_   _  ___ 
| '_ \| | | | |/ _ \
| |_) | | |_| |  __/
|_.__/|_|\__,_|\___|

[0m
```

Comment: thnx. the problem was with the file name

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds obvious but make sure that the lib is installed on your computer. If it is then make sure the lib is installed the same place your Python is installed.

Comment: the problem was with the file name.